# How to insert markdown text on a page cross-site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am receiving markdown-formatted text from another site using `script` tags. It works fine on on-line texts, however if it comes with linebreaks I am getting a console error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

A text example I get from the server:

```
var body = "<p>Introductions</p>

<p>Hi! I&#39;m Professor Franklin Risby. Pleased to make your acquaintance. We&#39;ll be spending some time together, as I&#39;m supposed to teach you...</p>

<p>I won&#39;t assume any previous functional programming knowledge....</p>";
      $('script#s_parent').after("<div class='pagemash_parent'></div>");
      $('._parent').html(body);
```

Comment: What you get from a server is not text but a javascript snippet, right?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel yes, exactly. I have a script widget that pushes info onto my page

Comment: I did same thing in one app and if I can share any advice it is: don't do it. Return response as json and handle it in the fronted (if js classes where you insert the text change) or just return a whole html snippet and paste it in. JS code in server responses is VERY troublesome and can lead to unpredicted issues, cross browser compatibility problems.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel thank you, I was leaning towards the HTML snippet pasting before, but was not sure, and now I am stuck with js responses. Can you please tell me what type of response does my server has to send in order to paste a whole HTML piece in?

Comment: I don't think anything will happen automatically for you (unless you use [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/)), you will have to code handling of the response on the fronted (so just move your code from response to ajax/click handler)